# Utility of management of Dynamics AX

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, ax

What is the utility of management utilities on Dynamics AX?

When should I use it? I'm preparing to install the  Dynamics AX and I find to minimize environment. All help suggest to because utility of management and don't say what!

Comment: You should be more specific than that. Which part exactly is your problem?

Comment: The question was vague indeed, but the answer seemed cover his needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to the [management utilities of AX 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg751346.aspx)? This is not a beginner subject.

Management utilities let you configure and manage Microsoft Dynamics AX components and artifacts. Use these utilities to deploy artifacts, such as reports and Web controls, from the metadata store.

This include command line tools such as [axutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh352314.aspx) and [signtool](http://rmdax2012.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-isv-models-but-were-afraid-to-ask/) which is usually located in %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\ManagementUtilities.

Read the link article then come back and improve your question.